# What's pink and quite solvable in the morning?

Tags: visual, cipher

I know this is probably a question for Finance SE, but they are an intimidating bunch over there - I hope somebody here may be able to help.

With the recent turmoil, I thought I should really try to understand how the economy works, in order to make the best decisions with my money. So this morning I decided to hop to my favourite newsagent and treat myself to a copy of the Financial Times. I wasn't ready for what I found!

Puzzlers, I'm puzzled! None of those graphs make sense to me, there are pages full of tiny numbers, and I haven't even got a clue what the ads are trying to sell me!

I copied an example below. There wasn't a caption, so I have no idea what it is. I wonder if someone could explain it to me - I am sure Economics is one of those things where you only need to get started, then you can work out the rest.

[image]

(Text version [here](https://pastebin.com/fasvxHqT))

Comment: Highlighting ranges (e.g. 0.30 to 0.40) differently by color, it looks like the lowest range may be forming some characters -> https://imgur.com/a/rTfKXqb

Comment: There are very few unique numbers in this data set, wonder if that might be part of the solution.

Comment: @BarryPoppins I've discovered the method, how do I know what the key is?

Comment: This is 100% Vigenere Cipher: https://imgur.com/a/wrYN960
Just not sure how to continue. I weighted the data-set in half (so highlights above and below 0.50)

Comment: @nine9 did you try 'sheet'?

Comment: @nine9, you've already found the key - or part of it...

Comment: @BarryPoppins, I'm desperate for another clue :)

Comment: @nine9 - it looks like I've misjudged how solvable it was - sorry about that, a lesson to learn! The last sentence of the flavour text ("you only need to get started") is meant to be a hint to the method (as you pointed out, it is a variant of Vigenere, but...). As I said in my previous comment, you have already found the key - it's there in gray and pink!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1 (as solved by @nine9)

> Highlighting the low values of the grid gives us "Vigenere"
> [image]

Step 2

> It's an autokeyed Vigenere cipher with an initial key of "Vigenere". Autokey meaning the full key is `initialKey + plainText`

The message is

> [Posterity will never survey a nobler grave than this: here lie the bones of Castlereagh: stop, traveler, and piss - George Gordon](https://allauthor.com/quotes/72052/)